# Shift Google Static Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I have a (lat,lon) pair that I want to plot on a static map.
However, I am going to have a dialog overlayed on the bottom half of the map, therefore I'd like to "shift" the map upwards such that the balloon is on the upper half of the image.

To illustrate, here is a map centered on San Francisco (37.7833,-122.4167), with the balloon placed at the center.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7833,-122.4167&zoom=15&size=400x400&markers=color:red|37.7833,-122.4167
```

[image: San Francisco]

What I would like is a map that looks something like this. I manually adjusted the center latitude by some decimals to shift upwards.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7803,-122.4167&zoom=15&size=400x400&markers=color:red|37.7833,-122.4167
```

[image: San Francisco Shifted]

Arbitrarily subtracting the latitude does not seem like the best approach to me and was wondering if anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: Can you not just use a smaller map height, and use up the remaining height with another div to place your content in?

Comment: Do you have to use the Static Maps API?  If you used the JS API, you could use the [geometry.spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) library, specifically the computeOffset method.  I don't think this is available with the Web Services API, which if it were could have been used to provide a value for your call to the Static Maps API

Answer (score 0):

You may request a larger map and then e.g. clip the image by the desired value.

Or use the image as a background-image and shift it via background-position:

```html
<div style="width:400px;
            height:400px;
            background-image:url(https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7833,-122.4167&zoom=15&size=400x600&markers=color:red|37.7833,-122.4167);
            background-position:0 -200px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be practical in all cases (depends on what you do with zoom), but a simple solution is to specify the map image with a height offset, then give it position absolute in a shorter div, like this:

HTML

```
    <div id = "container">
       <img src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7803,-122.4167&zoom=15&size=400x500&markers=color:red|37.7803,-122.4167"/>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container > img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kvbm1ekg/)